# URLs and linking abruptly broken in Angular / Django app

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django

Recently, something changed on my Django / Angular app that broke all of my front-end URLs and links.

For example, our root domain has stayed the same, but our location URLs changed from `/<campus.slug>/#campus_info` to `/<campus.slug>/#/campus_info` and it's breaking every link throughout our site.

I tried using `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` and `<base>` to change the base URL of our site, but it didn't fix them. I can't seem to make in-page anchor links work either. The only links that work now are Django links.

Has anyone else encountered an issue like this? I'm completely lost on how this even broke. I haven't touched routing or URL stuff in months on the site, and that's what's even more confusing to me.

Any feedback or tips would be appreciated on this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [**this**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4608) article, `$location` interferes with some versions of UI-Bootstrap and can have adverse effects on your URLs.

After removing a `$location` dependency from my controller that was affecting this code, I was able to fix my URL's and get all my anchor links and SPA linking working again.